# how to create sub menu in magento admin using module

Tags: magento

I'm developing magento module.I would like to add menu in admin section.

like.

> admin-> catalog -> Attributes -> Manage Attribute-> **Here mymenu**

Magento version 1.5.1.0

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

in your module's `adminhtml.xml` put the following:

```
    <config>
        <menu>
            <catalog>
                <children>
                    <attributes>
                        <children>
                            <attributes>
                                <children>
                                    <submenu translate="title" module="catalog">
                                        <title>submenu submenu</title>
                                        <action>adminhtml/catalog_product_attribute_submenu/</action>
                                    </submenu>
                                </children>
                            </attributes>
                        </children>
                    </attributes>
                </children>
            </catalog>
        </menu>
    </config>
```

Comment: :This is awesome thank you so much.i don't have double upvote